# What does COALESCE do in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server-2005, coalesce

I want to know what does coalesce do in this case, I know it returns first non null value and I have gone through this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) as well.

I want to know what does it do specifically here:

```
DECLARE @EMPNO NUMERIC(22,5)

SELECT @EMPNO = ''

SELECT @EMPNO = COALESCE(?, 0)
```

My intention in writing these statements is if @EMPNO is blank I want it to be replaced with zero instead. I'm afraid that I was able to achieve this out of these three statements.

Help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to do like this:

```
SELECT @EMPNO = COALESCE(@EMPNO, 0)
```

You know you can also write

```
SET @EMPNO = COALESCE(@EMPNO, 0)
```

You cannot set a `NUMERIC` to an empty varchar. You have to set it to `NULL`. So you full code should be like this:

```
DECLARE @EMPNO NUMERIC(22,5)
SELECT @EMPNO = NULL
SELECT @EMPNO = COALESCE(@EMPNO, 0)
```

Or you do not even need the to set the `@EMPNO` to `NULL`. When you declare a variable it is `NULL` by default. So the only thing you need is this:

```
DECLARE @EMPNO NUMERIC(22,5)
SELECT @EMPNO = COALESCE(@EMPNO, 0)
```

If you read on msdn it says:

> Returns the first nonnull expression among its arguments.

Reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258244%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Comment: This is the error i'm getting: Error converting data type varchar to numeric.